# Error: Boolean value of NA is ambiguous. I have no NAs in dataframe

Tags: python, na, stock, ambiguous, refinitiv-eikon

I'm connected to refinitiv to get data of stock prices because I'm trying to optimize my portfolio, the following code is how I got the data:

```
stocks_list = ['STLAM.MI','AAPL.O','AMZN.OQ','BULTEN.ST','PRIO3.SA','SEPL.L', 'HAL.N', 'TOU.TO', 'TYMN.L', 'kimbera.mx', '005930.KS' ]


def get_prices(stocks, start_date):
    stock_prices, err = ek.get_data(stocks,
                         ['TR.PriceClose.date','TR.PriceClose'],
                         {'SDate':start_date, 'EDate':'0D'})
    stock_prices['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(stock_prices['Date'])
    stock_prices = stock_prices.set_index(['Date','Instrument'])
    stock_prices = stock_prices.unstack()
    stock_prices.columns = stock_prices.columns.get_level_values(1)
    return stock_prices
prices = get_prices(stocks_list, start_date='-2Y').dropna()
ax = prices.rebase().plot()
```

After that chunk of code I'm trying to display the stock prices stats with the following code:

```
np.seterr(all='ignore')
stats = prices.calc_stats()
stats.display()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 2
      1 np.seterr(all='ignore')
----> 2 stats = prices.calc_stats()
      3 stats.display()

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffn/core.py:1231, in calc_stats(prices)
   1229     return PerformanceStats(prices)
   1230 elif isinstance(prices, pd.DataFrame):
-> 1231     return GroupStats(*[prices[x] for x in prices.columns])
   1232 else:
   1233     raise NotImplementedError("Unsupported type")

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffn/core.py:838, in GroupStats.__init__(self, *prices)
    836 self._end = self._prices.index[-1]
    837 # calculate stats for entire series
--> 838 self._update(self._prices)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffn/core.py:848, in GroupStats._update(self, data)
    847 def _update(self, data):
--> 848     self._calculate(data)
    849     self._update_stats()

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffn/core.py:855, in GroupStats._calculate(self, data)
...
    323 # add first month

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/missing.pyx:382, in pandas._libs.missing.NAType.__bool__()

TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

I already dropped all of the NAs in the prices dataframe. I tried `prices.isna().sum()` to double check and I got 0 for all of my columns. I also tried `prices.fillna(0)` but that didn't work either. I got the same error message. What can I do to display the stock prices stats?

Comment: can you provide the full traceback of the the error?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to add the full traceback